# Custom data type class not being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **CustomProductProperty** model that allows users to have custom fields for their products, within that contains a **CustomDataType** model that is linked to database that handles user defined DataTypes.

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeID")]
    [Display(Name = "Product Type")]
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomProductProperty> CustomProperties { get; set; } 
}

[Table("CustomProductProperty")]
public class CustomProductProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomPropertyID { get; set; }

    public int CustomDataTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomDataTypeID")]
    public virtual CustomDataType DataType { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

[Table("CustomDataType")]
public class CustomDataType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomTypeID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public CustomDataTypes DataType { get; set; }
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModuleID")]
    public Module Module { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to display this in my view, I created a Display Template to handle the **ICollection<>** of **CustomProductProperty**  For some reason, the `DataType.PropertyName` is empty but `PropertyValue` is still returning the correct data, anyone know why `PropertyName` is empty?

```
@model IEnumerable<InventoryManager.Models.CustomProductProperty>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DataType.PropertyName)</th>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PropertyValue)</td>
</tr>    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some code to show how you pass this model to the view, but my guess is it's caused by Lazy Loading. You have `DataType` virtual property which you do not evaluate in controller, so it's not loaded from database... Use `Include` method in your LINQ query for eager loading

Comment: How to I force it to include if the controller is finding a product? The `DataType` is inside `IEnumberable<CustomProductProperty`

Also, Thanks for pointing it out, I keep forgetting about Lazy Loading haha, it's still a relatively new concept to me.

Comment: Usage of Include method is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx. It would be easier if you show us the query you use to retrieve data...

Comment: Well Initially all I was doing was `dbcontext.Products.Find(id)`

Comment: In this case something like this should work for you: `dbcontext.Products.Include("CustomProperties").Include("CustomProperties.DataType").Single(id)`

Comment: Oh, didn't know you can chain Includes

Comment: Based on the link I mentioned before, it should be enough to use just `dbcontext.Products.Include("CustomProperties.DataTy‌​pe").Single(id)`. This should load both CustomProperties and DataType properties for them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31923/discussion-between-chaoticloki-and-tdragon)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `DataType` property is being loaded before the model is passed to the view (if it's lazy loaded, this might not be the case).

Are you using an ORM? You might need to join it in first - if you give more detail on what type of provider you're using, we should be able to provide example code.